# htmlclean grunt task to not supress spaces separated by tags

Tags: html, node.js, gruntjs

I am using the htmlclean grunt task ( https://github.com/anseki/grunt-htmlclean ), it is doing job correctly. However the removal of some spaces has caused display issues, for example:

```
                    <span>
                        to <a></a>
                    </span>
```

Gets cleaned to:

```
                    <span>to<a></a></span>
```

The spaces before and after the word 'to' is very important. I've had a look at the options of the task however I cannot see how to configure the task to respect such spaces.

Answer (score 0):

The htmlclean task allows using the `protect` option to prevent stripping whitespace from matching strings. You can set a regex that matches a word followed by an opening tag, e.g.

```
grunt.initConfig({
  htmlclean: {
    options: {
      protect: /\w(\s+)</g
    }
  }
});
```

See https://github.com/anseki/grunt-htmlclean#overview for the options.